# How do I get the value from <img> and pass to function?

Tags: reactjs, image, fetch

Consider the code below:

```
    {Object.keys(data).map((key) => 
        <div className="card">
        <img 
          id={ data[key].id }
          src={this.image} // 
          className="img-card-top"
          style={{height:"14rem"}} 
          alt="recipe"
         />
    }
```

So from this `<img>` I want to get the `id={ data[key].id }` and pass to the function of image

```
    image(id){
          // const id = this.state.data.id;
          fetch(`http://localhost:9000/api/item/photo/view/${id}`,)
          .then((resp)=>{
            resp.json().then((res)=>{
             console.log(res);
             this.setState({data: res.data});}
            )
            // console.log(this.state.data)
          })
        }
```

So the `id` I get from `<img>` will pass to the `fetch` API in `image()`.
What is the correct way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

Just use dynamic url as src, no need to use `fetch(url)`

```js
{Object.keys(data).map((key) => 
  <div className="card">
    <img 
        id={ data[key].id }
        src={`http://localhost:9000/api/item/photo/view/${id}`} 
        className="img-card-top"
        style={{height:"14rem"}} 
        alt="recipe"
    />
  </div>
)}
```

Comment: @kokoka budy, at least you should know how to fix that. I hope you do some coding by yourself as well instead of just copy pasting. replace `id` with `data[key].id`